# Group by and Order by latest

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to group by id and order by begintime(latest row).

data:

```
begintime           id  type    created_at
2012-12-13 01:00:00 1   type1   2012-12-01 11:39:47
2012-12-13 00:00:00 1   type2   2012-12-02 00:29:10
2012-12-13 03:00:00 2   type3   2012-12-05 00:20:43
2012-12-13 02:00:00 2   type2   2012-12-06 11:31:41
2012-12-13 00:00:00 2   type1   2012-12-07 00:58:11
```

I want to get:

```
begintime   id  type    created_at
2012-12-13 01:00:00 1   type1   2012-12-01 11:39:47
2012-12-13 03:00:00 2   type3   2012-12-05 00:20:43
```

How can I get it?

Comment: can you please explain what do you need?

Answer (score 3):

Your title contradicts from the question you have written. It says `LATEST` but you really want the first `created_AT` for every `ID`. Anyway,

You could use a subquery which separately gets the minimum `created_AT` for every `ID`. The result of the subquery is then joined back to get the values of the other columns.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID, MIN(created_AT) max_date
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY ID
        ) b ON  a.ID = b.ID AND
                a.created_AT = b.max_date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd4c8/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY 
  id ASC, 
  begintime DESC;
```

Hope it helps!